# How to change template and then continue writing function?

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-views

So... I have a function to send email to user and then user has to input the body of that email.

**My views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        context = {'has_error': False, 'data': request.POST}
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        code = request.POST.get('code')

        letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
        numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",]
        characters = letters + numbers
        length = 5
        token = "".join(random.sample(characters, length))

        body = render_to_string('authentication/email/email_body.html', {
            'username': username,
            'token': token,
        })
        send_mail(
            "Email Confirmation",
            # f"Hello {username}! Your code to confirm your email is : {token}",
            body,
            'tadejtilinger@gmail.com',
            [email]
        )
        return render(request, 'authentication/email/email_confirmation.html', context={'token': token})
    return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html')
```

So here I tried to change template from `signup.html` to `email_confirmation.html`. I succeeded so now I want to tell python what it should do with `email_confirmation.html` but I don't know how to do it. If I try writing code under `return render(request, 'authentication/email/email_confirmation.html', context={'token': token})` it won't work. **Where and how should I actually write my code then?**

Thanks for help I hope I wrote question understanding!:)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new view that handles what `email_confirmation` does - otherwise you would be cramming far too much into a single view. Your template can just refer to another URL/view even though it's generated elsewhere.

```py
def signup(request):
   # your existing code

def confirm_email(request):
   # confirm email address and code are valid
```

The new view should have it's own URL in your `urls.py` file too.